# Convert date to timestamp mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, graphql, apollo

I have a problem with the date in MongoDB. When I create a post I get the date with `Date.now()`. When I check the DB it is stored as this: `ISODate("2018-12-08T09:40:38.623+0000")`.

If I do a normal GraphQL query I get as result: `"created_at": "1544262038623"`.
In my schema the query is defined as `created_at: String`. **Question number 1:** How can I make the query to show me the date and not the timestamp since epoch?

**Question number 2:** I want to get the timestamp to do some aggregate calculation. But there it's always in the date format and I can't get the timestamp, no matter what I do. I tried: $toDecimal, new Date("$created_at") and other things. How do I do that? I need the milliseconds since epoch like in the query above (1544262038623).

*Addiotional info: Working with mongoose and apollo. **MongoDB is mLab.***

```
Post.aggregate([
  { $match: { author_id: "uRKNnDZIv" }},
  { $addFields: { 
    timestamp: "$created_at"
  }
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert date to timestamp then you can use [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) aggregation

```
Post.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "author_id": "uRKNnDZIv" }},
  { "$addFields": { 
    "timestamp": { "$toLong": "$created_at" }
  }}
])
```

And If you want to convert timestamp to date then you can use [**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation

```
Post.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "author_id": "uRKNnDZIv" }},
  { "$addFields": { 
    "timestamp": { "$toDate": "$created_at" }
  }}
])
```